# Scientific Linux 7.1 (rhel 7.1) Gnucash from EPEL stopped working

Tags: linux, gnucash

Suddenly today I tried to launch GnuCash on my computer and nothing happened. I went to a terminal and tried to start the program and got:

```
gnucash: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: _gst_tag_list_type
```

For more specific on the OS:

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 8 10:11:15 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Googling only finds a question on this site about slackware, which I'm not at all sure would be applicable here.

How do I fix this?

Comment: seems like a bug. What version are you using `rpm -q gnucash`?

Comment: gnucash-2.6.6-1.el7.nux.x86_64 -- Huh, I thought it would have been from EPEL. Still nux has worked for me for everything else, and I don't recall any gnucash update recently. I wonder if I need an update? Of course, yum update only sees some kernel updates right now, which I will try to see if it helps.

Comment: EPEL has more recent version in ["testing"](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2015-121c7f7daa). You can give it a try: `yum --enablerepo=epel-testing update gnucash gnucash-docs`. It might solve the problems. If so, feel free to report to the update so it will move to stable. It stinks there for three months.

Answer (score 0):

EPEL has more recent version in ["testing updates"](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2015-121c7f7daa). You can give it a try using

```
yum --enablerepo=epel-testing update gnucash gnucash-docs
```

It might solve the problems. The old version is probably build against some older libraries.

If it worked for you, feel free to report (give karma) to the update so it will move to stable. It stinks there for a long time.

Comment: Sadly didn't change anything but the output of rpm -q gnucash. Same error.

Comment: so probably the ideal time to report the bug or at lest post a note, that it does not work,  to the update. It is probably dependent on some other package